# Si tengo algo nuevo qué preguntar ¿debo preguntarlo en ambos sitios?

Tags: discusión, faq

Voy a empezar con decir que estoy en contra de las traducciones autorrespondidas inmediatamente con el afán de obtener reputación de forma rápida.

Pero el caso que planteo es completamente diferente. Hice, por ejemplo, [ésta pregunta sobre un problema real](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/190/provisionar-m%C3%A1quina-de-vagrant-con-puppet-usando-el-m%C3%B3dulo-de-mysql) que llevo un muy buen rato tratando de resolver, y luego de haberla preguntado recordé que sólo somos 802 personas en la beta privada y que es un poco difícil que alguien la responda (dada la cantidad de visitas recibidas -6- vs las visitas promedio en otras preguntas -40-).

¿Sería correcto publicarla en el sitio SO inglés? 
En caso de alguien responderme en inglés, ¿Debo copiar su respuesta y ponerla acá? O bien, ¿debo dejar esa pregunta sin responder en español?

Me encantaría que la persona que me respondiera primero fuera bilingüe y pusiera su respuesta en ambos sitios pero es un poco improbable y menos en la beta privada.

¿Qué sería lo éticamente correcto?

[Regresar al índice del FAQ](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1378/)

Comment: Lo "éticamente correcto" es recompensar con votos a todas las personas que te ayuden con sus respuestas. Que preguntes en un sitio o en cien no tiene nada de malo (ni nada que ver con la ética, diría yo).

Comment: +1 , concuerdo con @Konamiman

Answer (score 26, accepted):

En mi opinión, dónde preguntas no tiene que ver con la ética. Puedes preguntarlo aquí, puedes preguntarlo en el SO inglés, puedes preguntarlo en ambos sitios, y puedes no preguntarlo en ningún sitio. No hay nada inmoral en ninguna de las opciones.

Hay más gente en el SO inglés, y por eso tal vez es más conveniente preguntar allí. No veo ningún problemas con esto. Y si alguien publica una buena respuesta aquí o allí, y quieres compartirla en el otro lenguaje, ¡qué bueno!

Yo he hecho esto: traduje [esta pregunta](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/444089/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8-z-z-index-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) en ruso [a inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32109258/why-doesnt-the-z-index-style-apply-to-the-body-element), obtuvo una [respuesta en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32111432/546661), y publiqué una [traducción de esa respuesta en ruso](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/444095/176684), con un enlace al original. Nadie se ha quejado por eso: hubo beneficios para todas las personas interesadas en ambos idiomas.

Answer (score 5):

## Respuesta corta

Coincido con la [respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/81/65) de [Peter Olson](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/416/peter-olson), si el autor lo desea puede publicar en varios sitios la misma pregunta. Considero que de hacerlo así debe incluir en las publicaciones derivadas un enlace a la publicación original y eventualmente incluir "backlinks" a las diversas publicaciones relacionadas con la original.

## Comentarios al margen

- Publicar la misma información en varios canales sin señalar esto, en
  inglés se conoce como `multiposting`.
- Cuando se indica que la misma información está siendo publicada en varios canales se le
  llama `cross-posting`
- Cuando la información se publica en un idioma
  distinto al original manteniendo el tono, estilo de redacción, etc.
  se le llama `traducción`.
- Cuando la información se publica basada en
  otra información, pero a esta se le han hecho adecuaciones por
  diversas causas, como el cambio de estilo de redacción se le llama adaptación.
- Cuando sólo se toman ciertos elementos para transmitir las ideas principales pero introduciendo otros elementos se dice que la publicación
  `está basada en` la publicación original.

En cualquier caso, cuando existe una publicación original, lo correcto es citar apropiadamente la publicación original aún y cuando las publicaciones derivadas sean realizadas por el autor original. Cuando todas las instancias son idénticas, señalar que la publicación ha sido *publicada de forma cruzada* (cross-posted).