# ¿Se puede realizar la misma pregunta en SOen aunque en SOes ya esta haya sido respondida correctamente?

Tags: discusión, soporte

En si es eso, por ejemplo, hay X pregunta en SOes la cual ya fue respondida y aceptada por el autor, ¿Se puede realizar la misma pregunta en SOen aunque en SOes esta ya haya sido respondida y aceptada?

Comment: Claro, pero siempre y cuando hagas una busqueda en SOen también para asegurarte de que no estás formulando una pregunta que ya se ha hecho y contestado en SOen anteriormente.

Comment: Según entiendo se debe usar sólo una etiqueta obligatoria. Me parece que en esta corresponde soporte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aunque Stack Overflow y Stack Overflow en español tratan sobre temas muy similares, son dos comunidades diferentes, empezando porque la primera es inglés y la segunda en español, así que mientras la pregunta siga los lineamientos de cada sitio y sea de un tema específico de interés de cada comunidad seguramente será bien recibida por cada una.

Relacionado: [Si tengo algo nuevo qué preguntar ¿debo preguntarlo en ambos sitios?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/76/si-tengo-algo-nuevo-qu%C3%A9-preguntar-debo-preguntarlo-en-ambos-sitios)

Comment: ¿Serían duplicadas? (No estoy seguro)

Comment: En términos generales tratan de lo mismo pero me parece que si bien las respuestas son "consistentes" tienen "matices" diferentes, concretamente las circunstancias, allá habla de publicar en ambos sitios de forma simultánea y acá trata de transferir las preguntas (y yo diría incluyendo su respuesta) de sitio en español al sitio en inglés, lo cual es inusual (lo usual es en en el sentido contrario).