# ¿Es válido hacer preguntas de temas que están en otros sitios o que ya tenga la solución de dicha pregunta?

Tags: discusión

Bueno mi pregunta es si es bien visto que por ejemplo yo tengo un problema en alguna parte de mi código y paso un tiempo sin poder resolverlo, lo investigo y me doy cuenta que esta la respuesta en algun otro sitio ya sea en inglés o en español y se me ocurre la idea de publicarlo aqui en `SOes`.

Yo no respondo a mi propia publicación sino a la persona que se acerca mas a mi respuesta que ya habia encontrado, eso lo hago con el motivo de hacer crecer cada vez mas la basde de datos de información de preguntas de este sitio ya que se me hace una muy buena idea.

Yo no me encargo de traducir las preguntas que están en inglés al español, sino con base a mi problema y a la información que encontré en diferentes partes, soluciono un problema y ya una vez solucionado pienso en que mas personas pueden tener el mismo problema y lo publico en esta plataforma. ¿Eso se considera como algo ético o válido?. Por cierto, eso no pasa todo el tiempo ya que muchas de mis preguntas sí las hago porque aún no tengo la solución.

Comment: Como bien mencionas, es válido responder a tus propias preguntas, de hecho si ninguna respuesta satisface tu necesidad, éso sería lo ideal. También podrías incluir las referencias de donde encontraste una solución, o el código, esto sería más ético. No tiene nada de malo decir al final de tu propia respuesta "*...en este link de SO en inglés se expuso el mismo problema y su solución es la que yo requería.*". También puedes responder a tu pregunta como Wiki de Comunidad. Como verás, hay varias opciones, no hay nada peleado con compartir conocimientos, todo lo contrario :)

Comment: [[relacionado](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/76/si-tengo-algo-nuevo-qu%C3%A9-preguntar-debo-preguntarlo-en-ambos-sitios)]